# How to always have a ValueError exception until the input is a valid number?

Tags: python, valueerror

```
def mainloop():
    inp = input("Which cipher would you like to use?\n[A]a1z26\n[B]Atbash\n[C]Caesar\n[D]ROT13\n>")
    elif inp.lower() == 'c':
        inp = input("Would you like to decipher or encipher a text?\n>")
        while inp.lower() not in ('decipher', 'encipher'):
            inp = input("Please enter either 'decipher' or 'encipher'.\n>")
        if inp.lower() == 'decipher':
            inp1 = input("What text would you like to decipher?\n>")
            while True:
                try:
                    inp2 = int(inp2)
                except ValueError:
                    inp2 = int(input("Please enter a valid number.\n>"))
            dec_caesar(inp1, inp2)
```

So the code by itself works and edge cases have already been implemented in my code but I made it shorter so it is easier to read.  Essentially what I want is to have `inp2` be a number of shift for the cipher, eg if `inp2 == 1` and the letter is a it would shift by 1 to become `b`, and I've already coded this.  The problem is handling the case when `inp2` cannot be an integer.  By default an input is a `string` so I use `int(input)` and the except `ValueError` works the first time, but if i type a `string` again, it will just Raise a `ValueError` instead of running the except `ValueError`.  How can I make it so it would keep asking to enter a valid number until `int(input)` is valid?

the above code produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/justin/Documents/PycharmProjects/cipher.py", line 97, in mainloop
    inp2 = int(inp2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/justin/Documents/PycharmProjects/cipher.py", line 105, in <module>
    mainloop()
  File "C:/Users/justin/Documents/PycharmProjects/cipher.py", line 99, in mainloop
    inp2 = int(input("Please enter a valid number.\n>"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems you can address here.

1. You are running a `while` loop over `while True` which will always run unless you call `break`
2. You are running your "check" in the except clause, which does not have a try except block of its own.

We can set `inp2` to `None` earlier in the code and use our while loop to monitor the status of the variable.

Then we only need to check if the value is an integer during our try clause, and when a successful response is entered, the loop will terminate.

```
def mainloop():
    inp2 = None
    while inp2 == None:
        try:
            inp2 = int(input("How much would you like to shift the text by?\n>"))
        except ValueError:
            print("You can only enter integer values!")
            continue
```

When run, this is your result. Note the error is due to you not having the function defition in your posts code, this should work fine when run in your environment.

```
Would you like to decipher or encipher a text?
>decipher
How much would you like to shift the text by?
>a
How much would you like to shift the text by?
>f
How much would you like to shift the text by?
>a
How much would you like to shift the text by?
>e
How much would you like to shift the text by?
>2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
    mainloop()
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 15, in mainloop
    dec_caesar(inp, inp2)
NameError: name 'dec_caesar' is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks this works well. Much appreciated.